# How to update a DateField in Django from a json object

Tags: django, django-models

I would like to repopulate a DateField in my database ..for example for this `"EXPIRYDATE": "2016-Sep-02",` json value I get `Feb. 2, 2016` in my database

```
expirydate = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

This will try to loop through two objects in a list one in French and one in English so I'll try to update the `expirydate` field but it's not the proper value.

```
for lang in [0,1]:
    jobs_lang = data[lang]['jobs']
    for job in jobs_lang:
        emploi= Job.objects.filter(jobref=job['JOBREF'])
        if (emploi[0].expirydate != job['EXPIRYDATE']):
            emploi[0].expirydate = job['EXPIRYDATE']
            emploi[0].save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the date format is going to be consistent, you can use the `datetime` module's `strptime` function to parse the date string:

```
import datetime

# the date_format should match what's provided in the JSON
date_format = '%Y-%b-%d' 
emploi[0].expirydate = datetime.datetime.strptime(job['EXPIRYDATE'], date_format)
```

Here, `date_obj` will be an object you save via the Django ORM into the database.

Also see https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior for alternate format strings.

Comment: Thanks @Derek but I get my data from the [opendata](http://www.ottawacityjobs.ca/en/data/) but when I apply your answers it always gives me `2016-02-02`` so today's date. But when I tryied it for 'POSTDATE` it gives me the right answer.

Comment: Thanks! Merci! for the help. Your simplify version makes me realize how beautiful a code can be :)